# React App not working on Microsoft Edge browser, but working fine on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: reactjs

The app is running fine on chrome and firefox but not working on Edge.This is my package.json. I am using create-react-app.

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^0.1.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "joi": "^17.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "little-state-machine": "^3.0.3",
    "little-state-machine-devtools": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-google-autocomplete": "^1.2.6",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.0.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-stepzilla": "^6.0.2",
    "react-table": "^7.5.0",
    "react-to-print": "^2.9.0",
    "react-toastify": "^6.0.8",
    "recoil": "0.0.10",
    "underscore": "^1.10.2",
    "yup": "^0.29.2"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
    ]
}
```

}

I am getting this error in Edge

> SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number. In 1.chunk.js

It points to the second line of the following code. The one with the spread operator.

```
function setUnvalidatedAtomValue(state, key, newValue) {
  return { ...state,
  atomValues: mapByDeletingFromMap$1(state.atomValues, key),
  nonvalidatedAtoms: mapBySettingInMap$1(state.nonvalidatedAtoms, key, newValue),
  dirtyAtoms: setByAddingToSet$1(state.dirtyAtoms, key)
 };
} // Set a node value and return the set of nodes that were actually written.
// That does not include any downstream nodes which are dependent on them.
```

Now i think this maybe due to the spread operator not being supported by Edge. I think maybe using recoiljs for global state managment maybe causing the issue, but i am not very sure. Any way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume this is an issue during development, and not in production (correct me if I'm wrong there). According to the create-react-app website [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features) the development environment is targeted towards modern browsers so that modern js features like async/await, import statements, and destructuring are supported. According to that link, it seems that adding Edge to `browserlist.development` should ensure that it is supported during development. Note that in production create-react-app converts the react code to es5, which shouldn't have support issues, however, see the note about polyfills and runtime support on the create-react-app link above as those require additional consideration.